# Count Rows Error in Trigger

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I wrote this trigger below. it is generating Error at `COUNT(*) From`. I want that when any row inserts into table 'Users' with this trigger currently present folders in Assignments should assign to User.[image]

For Example: I add new row to table `Users` suppose `userD`. Then with the help of this trigger Present folders like `folderA, folderB, folderC` should assign to `userD` with folder right `Visible` by default. I have written this Trigger below but it is givig Error at `Count(*) From`

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trigger_Insert ON Users
FOR INSERT
AS
    declare @userid int;
    declare @username nvarchar(50);
    declare @useremail nvarchar(50);
    declare @userpassword nvarchar(50);

    select @userid=i.user_id from inserted i;   
    select @username=i.user_name from inserted i;   
    select @useremail=i.user_email from inserted i; 
    select @userpassword=i.user_password from inserted i;
    DECLARE @intFlag INT
    SET @intFlag =1
    WHILE (@intFlag <=COUNT(*) FROM Assignments;)  // Error Here
    BEGIN
       insert into UAssignment_Rights(
       ua_rights_id,ua_rights_name,assignment_id,user_id) 
       values(@userid,'Visible','','');
       SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
       PRINT 'AFTER INSERT trigger fired.'
    END 
GO
```

Can you please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Never assume that `inserted` contains one record only because in Sql Server trigger is fired once per statement, and that statement might have been `insert into ... select` resulting in 0, 1 or many rows. That being said, what do you want to insert? Here you create number of identical rows. You probably do not need loop anyway, because you can insert the results of a select: [see this link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/08/10/sql-server-use-insert-into-select-instead-of-cursor/).

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović how to achieve my goal. Please make your comment more clear. I am bit confuse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer updated to comply with info from comments.

My point is that most of the times you do not need loops or cursor in Sql Server. Usually set based approach is simpler and faster. In this case you might use form of `insert` that does not insert fixed values but rather result of `select`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trigger_Insert ON Users
FOR INSERT
AS
-- this is mandatory in trigger - you do not want @@rowcount reported to applications
-- to change as a result of statement in trigger (all of them, including set and select)

    set nocount on

-- You can simply take assignment_id directly from Assignments table
    insert into UAssignment_Rights(ua_rights_name, assignment_id, user_id)
    select 'Visible', a.assignment_id, i.user_id
      from Inserted i
     cross join dbo.Assignments a

    PRINT 'AFTER INSERT trigger fired.'
GO
```

P.S. [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) is result of join without join condition. Meaning that returned rows are all possible cobinations of each row from left table with each row from right table.

Comment: By far the best answer.

Comment: Thank you Sir. Can you please explain me `insert Cartesian product of Assignments and inserted tables` ? as i am new to all this.

Comment: `WHILE @intFlag <= (SELECT COUNT(assignment_id) FROM Assignments)
    BEGIN
 SET @int = (SELECT assignment_id FROM Assignments where assignment_id=@intFlag)
       insert into UAssignment_Rights(ua_rights_name,assignment_id,user_id) 
        values('Visible',@intFlag,@userid);
       SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1`   I want to insert assignment_id so how to do this?

Comment: @ZoyaSheikh You can simply take assignment_id directly from Assignments table. Please take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović Thank you sir. and one last question : can i copy this same code for update-trigger and delete-trigger?

Comment: @ZoyaSheikh I don't think so. What do you want update and delete triggers to do?

Answer (score 2):

`COUNT(*)` should only be used as part of a `SELECT` or `HAVING` statement, [see MSDN for more information on aggregate functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx).

If `Assignments` will not change as part of the `WHILE` loop, try replacing...

```
WHILE (@intFlag <=COUNT(*) FROM Assignments;)  // Error Here
```

With...

```
DECLARE @AssignmentsCount INT
SELECT @AssignmentsCount = COUNT(*) FROM Assignments
WHILE @intFlag <= @AssignmentsCount
```

This means that the `COUNT(*)` is only done once.

However, if the number of `Assignments` **could** change during the loop, the replace it with...

```
WHILE @intFlag <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Assignments)
```

Comment: NO do not encourage the use of scalar variables from inserted. This is somethign that should under no circumstance be done in a trigger. Inserted can contain multiple rows!!!!

Comment: Point taken @HLGEM. To be honest, I very rarely touch triggers, I think them dangerous as they're not obviously there

Comment: I think it is far more dangerous not to have them when you want to maintain data integrity, but then I work with trying to fix databases that other people broke with bad design. Trust me, data integrity is NEVER succesfully maintained from an application. I base that on 30 years working with hundreds of databases that covered a lot of subect areas.

Comment: I see where you're coming from @HLGEM. And despite removing the part you object to, you don't remove the down-vote.  Suit yourself

Comment: Thank you @HLGEM, that's appreciated